Is it possible to develop a multifunctions token?
i try to know where the capabilities of smart contract are, is it possible to write a smart contract for a token that will be :
Ownable
Transferable
Burnable
POS Compatible
POW emulated compatible
Airdrop Compatible
zk-SNARK Compatible
Bridges compatible
The POW will be emulated by another contract.
I'm junior dev, which approch i have to learn ?
Best regards

Take a look at OpenZeppelin's Wizard. It allows to create a token and select different features from a menu.
Isolate each feature in a separate contract, then using inheritance you could create the token with multiple features.

Thank you for this response.
